# How to restore information about partial class from DLL?

Tags: c#, partial, reflector, disassembly

DLL contains partial class `DisPart` defined in two places:

```
public partial class DisPart
{
    public static string s;
}


public partial class DisPart
{
    public static int i;
}
```

Disassembling the DLL in `Reflector` results in:

```
public class DisPart
{
    public static int i;
    public static string s;
}
```

Is there any possibility to restore information:

1)whether the class was `partial`?

2)how the class's members definitions were divided ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PDB file would probably indicate both of these, as it will contain line number information - at least for the methods (and I'd *expect* for variables too). I don't *expect* it would be in the DLL itself. I also don't know how easy it would be to discover even if you had the PDB, to be honest - I don't know what the format of a PDB file is.

Answer (score 1):

No, the partial modifier is only for the use of the maker of the class, so that it can be separated across multiple files. At compile time, the parts of the class are fused together.